# Modular Markers on on Google Map in Ember

Tags: google-maps, ember.js

Rendering Markers on a Map in Ember.

I want `/map` to show a map with a bunch of different types of markers on it. I would like these markers to be completely modular from the map.

Here is my `MapRoute`:

```
App.MapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.store.find('marker', this.paramsFor(this.routeName)).then(function(result){
      this.controllerFor('markers').set('model', result);
    }
  }
});
```

I have a `MapView` that initializes the google map object and has an attribute named `map` that has the google map object.

In my `MarkersController`:

```
App.MarkersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   arrayContentDidChange: function() {
      // Accesss the google map object in the MapView
      // Render all markers
   }
});
```

**How do I access the google map from the MapView in the MarkersController?**

One thought was to have the `MapController` know about the MapView and have the `MarkersController` "need" the `MapController`. But I feel like it is bad practice for the controller to know its view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the `MapView` from inside the `MarkersView` by using `this.get('parentView')`:

```
App.MarkersView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
     console.log(this.get('parentView'));
  }
});
```

This is where your view logic and behavior should live. If you need to do data manipulation, you should use `needs` in the controller as you stated, I think.